# Printing additional line when using System.in.read()

Tags: java

```
public class DWDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {

        char ch;

        do {
            System.out.print("Press a key followed by ENTER: ");
            ch = (char) System.in.read();
        } while (ch != 'S');
    }
}
```

Trying to learn java. It's a simple function however the result I get is

```
Press a key followed by ENTER: D
Press a key followed by ENTER: Press a key followed by ENTER: G
Press a key followed by ENTER: Press a key followed by ENTER: E
Press a key followed by ENTER: Press a key followed by ENTER: F
Press a key followed by ENTER: Press a key followed by ENTER: S
```

System will print "Press a key followed by Enter:" twice in Intellij and in eclipse will print three times.

Please help!

Comment: `Press a key followed by ENTER` can't see this in your code above?

Comment: Yeah, I just don't understand it will print twice after I enter a false value.

Comment: It seems that you should run it from command line. Agree with YoungHobbit!!

Comment: I agree with @YoungHobbit, but try adding this if you want a line break `\n`

Comment: That is because of the `new line character` after the actual character. I would suggest you to use the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for reading from STDIN.

Comment: Sorry being stupid. Now it's the correct code.

Comment: Thanks! @YoungHobbit can you explain the difference between Intellij and Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are reading char from console. Every "ENTER" == '\n' will be taken as a character. So your 
        `(char)System.in.read()`
taking 2 chars and loop gets incremented for every character it reads and for also "ENTER".

Comment: Follow-up question. Why when I use Intellij it print twice and when I try it on Eclipse it print three time?